# интеграция flake8 в pycharm

Tags: pycharm, flake8

Как выглядит(какое имя) и где находиться исполняемый файл flake8 на ubuntu? Не удаётся его найти, чтобы прописать в поле Program для интеграции flake8 в PyCharm
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотрите в `venv/bin/`